# Word stress in pick up your toys

Tags: word-stress

When you say "Pick up your toys", do you say "pick" and "up" with the same stress or is "up" stronger/louder? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose there is a correct way. I am British English and I would place no particular emphasis on any word. Moreover, unless I was speaking in anger, I would also add a "please" at the end, as in:

> Pick up your toys, please.

To my ears, any emphasis in this sentence sounds strange. However, if I was dealing with a naughty child, I might say:

> *You* can pick up *your* toys.

This would emphasise the fact that it is his/her responsibility to tidy up any mess they have made.

Answer (score 0):

American speaker here. I would say "*pick* up your *toys*" with *pick* being strong than *up*. However, I would say "pick it *up*!" emphasizing *up* only if it is the last word of the sentence.